# Scrolling Text Position Find Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making an AJAX call using a timer for content update. During this update I lose the scroll text position and the text is not scrolled fully. It stops scrolling when the page refresh happens in the AJAX call. I need the text to scroll fully without any disturbance.

To do that I am trying to find the scroll position using the `scrolltop` property but it is not working for me. Please help me to scroll the text fully without breakup during the AJAX call.

In my code I use a 2 second timer for the AJAX call and I am updating the page.

```html
<div class='marquee' style='margin-top:1px;background-color:#6ec1f8;'>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer()
}, 2000);

function myTimer() {
  var pos = $(".marquee").scrollTop();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "",
    data: '',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      var $response = $(data);
      var oneval = $response.find('#main_view').html();
      $('#main_view').html(oneval);
      $(".marquee").scrollTop(pos);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #333;
}

.marquee p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, AJAX polling every 2 seconds is an incredibly bad idea. It will put a lot of unnecessary load on your server. You can alleviate some of that by making the interval longer, say 30 seconds or more, depending on how important the client/server sync is in the data you're displaying. If it absolutely has to be kept in sync with the server, then you should be using Websockets. Secondly, to solve the issue, instead of overwriting all the content, append the new `p` elements to the end of the current content and remove those which are invisible to the left.

Comment: Our client asking 2 seconds update so that is the issue to find the scroll text position otherwise it is not needed is there any possibility to overcome this issue

Comment: If the client asks for something stupid (in terms of technical achievability) then it's your job as a dev to guide them to a better solution. However the solution is as I said above, append to the right, and remove the invisible to the left.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Spot on.